# IOS: create a UIImage or UIImageView with rounded corners

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimage, rounded-corners

Is it possible create an `UIImage` or an `UIImageView` with rounded corners? Because I want take an `UIImage` and show it inside an `UIImageView`, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 241, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.
Import the `QuartzCore`  (`#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`) header and play with the `layer` property of the `UIImageView`.

```
yourImageView.layer.cornerRadius = yourRadius;
yourImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

See the [CALayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) class reference for more info.

Comment: ok it work for an UIImageView but if I put inside this UIImageView an UIImage it don't work, how can I solve?

Comment: Don't forget to activate `clipToBounds`. `yourImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;`

Comment: If ImageView was inside of scrollView or tableView cell, clipsToBounds makes bad scroll performance.

Comment: I test this way! Cost lot of memory!

Comment: I have used this code in Swift 2.0, and it worked properly, thank you. By the way, I have changed YES by true.

Comment: This isn't really a bezel - it is a technically ROUNDED edge, but not in the way I think a lot of people probably want.  It is however one of the more creative ideas I've seen!

Comment: *yourImageView.layer.cornerRadius = youImageView.frame.width/2*
to make it acircle

Comment: just a reminder from 2019: don’t need to import `QuartzCore (#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>) header` anymore

Answer (score 54):

Try this Code For **Round Image** Import **QuartzCore** framework
**simple way** to create Round Image

```
imageView.layer.backgroundColor=[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
imageView.layer.cornerRadius=20;
imageView.layer.borderWidth=2.0;
imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
imageView.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
```

[image]

Answer (score 49):

Objective-C

```
-(UIImage *)makeRoundedImage:(UIImage *) image 
                      radius: (float) radius;
{
  CALayer *imageLayer = [CALayer layer];
  imageLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
  imageLayer.contents = (id) image.CGImage;

  imageLayer.masksToBounds = YES;
  imageLayer.cornerRadius = radius;

  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
  [imageLayer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
  UIImage *roundedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

  return roundedImage;
}
```

Swift 3

```
func makeRoundedImage(image: UIImage, radius: Float) -> UIImage {
    var imageLayer = CALayer()
    imageLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height)
    imageLayer.contents = image.cgImage

    imageLayer.masksToBounds = true
    imageLayer.cornerRadius = radius

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size)
    imageLayer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
    var roundedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return roundedImage
}
```

Comment: how to make image centre part create  curve shape slim how to possible  this concept please guy let me know for objective c language

Answer (score 10):

```
uiimageview.layer.cornerRadius = uiimageview.frame.size.height/2;
uiimageview.clipToBounds = YES;

#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Comment: How does this differ from other answers?

Comment: @Mark `uiimageview.frame.size.height/2;` is real gem to make an image perfect round shape, a full circle.

Comment: How do you come up with  uiimageview.frame.size.height/2? Can you please explain?

Comment: @IdreesAshraf a simple logic involved here .... radius of half height will start from top middle till left middle. making arc of 45degree. so having such arc on 4 sides will make a view perfect circle.

Comment: @Ans It will fail if I have image with different width and height. You can try that..

Answer (score 3):

```
// UIImageView+OSExt.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIImageView (OSExt)
- (void)setBorder:(CGFloat)borderWidth color:(UIColor*)color;
@end

// UIImageView+OSExt.m
#import "UIImageView+OSExt.h"

@implementation UIImageView (OSExt)
- (void)layoutSublayersOfLayer:(CALayer *)layer
{
    for ( CALayer *sub in layer.sublayers )
    {
        if ( YES == [sub.name isEqual:@"border-shape"])
        {
            CGFloat borderHalf = floor([(CAShapeLayer*)sub lineWidth] * .5);
            sub.frame = layer.bounds;
            [sub setBounds:CGRectInset(layer.bounds, borderHalf, borderHalf)];
            [sub setPosition:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(layer.bounds),
                                       CGRectGetMidY(layer.bounds))];
        }
    }
}

- (void)setBorder:(CGFloat)borderWidth color:(UIColor*)color
{
    assert(self.frame.size.width == self.frame.size.height);
    for ( CALayer *sub in [NSArray arrayWithArray:self.layer.sublayers] )
    {
        if ( YES == [sub.name isEqual:@"border-shape"])
        {
            [sub removeFromSuperlayer];
            break;
        }
    }

    CGFloat borderHalf = floor(borderWidth * .5);
    self.layer.cornerRadius = self.layer.bounds.size.width * .5;

    CAShapeLayer *circleLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    self.layer.delegate = (id<CALayerDelegate>)self;
    circleLayer.name = @"border-shape";
    [circleLayer setBounds:CGRectInset(self.bounds, borderHalf, borderHalf)];
    [circleLayer setPosition:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.layer.bounds),
                                         CGRectGetMidY(self.layer.bounds))];
    [circleLayer setPath:[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:circleLayer.bounds] CGPath]];
    [circleLayer setStrokeColor:color.CGColor];
    [circleLayer setFillColor:[UIColor clearColor].CGColor];
    [circleLayer setLineWidth:borderWidth];

    {
    circleLayer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero;
    circleLayer.shadowColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
    circleLayer.shadowRadius = borderWidth;
    circleLayer.shadowOpacity = .9f;
    circleLayer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero;
    }

    // Add the sublayer to the image view's layer tree
    [self.layer addSublayer:circleLayer];

    // old variant
    //CALayer *layer = self.layer;
    //layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    //layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width * 0.5;
    //layer.borderWidth = borderWidth;
    //layer.borderColor = color;
}
@end
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like a little bit of the image bleeds through past the border. I'm not sure if there's an easy fix for that…

Comment: border improved

Answer (score 2):

Setting `cornerRadius` and `clipsToBounds` is the right way to do this. However if the view's size changes, the radius will not update. In order to get proper resizing and animation behavior, you need to create a `UIImageView` subclass.

```
class RoundImageView: UIImageView {
    override var bounds: CGRect {
        get {
            return super.bounds
        }
        set {
            super.bounds = newValue
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        layer.cornerRadius = bounds.width / 2.0
        clipsToBounds = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this to get rounded corners of the image View and also to colour the corners:

```
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.height/2;
imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
imageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:148/255. green:79/255. blue:216/255. alpha:1.0].CGColor;
imageView.layer.borderWidth=2;
```

Condition*: The height and the width of the imageView must be same to get rounded corners.

Answer (score 1):

1. layer.cornerRadius = imageviewHeight/2
2. layer.masksToBounds = true

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but I'll advice you to create transparent png image (mask) with round corners and place it over you image with UIImageView. It might be quicker solution (for example if you need animations or scrolling).

Answer (score 0):

Here how i set my rounded avatar at the center of it contain view:

```
-(void)setRoundedAvatar:(UIImageView *)avatarView toDiameter:(float)newSize atView:(UIView *)containedView;
{
    avatarView.layer.cornerRadius = newSize/2;
    avatarView.clipsToBounds = YES;

    avatarView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize, newSize);
    CGPoint centerValue = CGPointMake(containView.frame.size.width/2, containedView.frame.size.height/2);
    avatarView.center = centerValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Circle with UIBeizerPath #Swift-3 && #imageExtension**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageOutlet: UIImageView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let image = UIImage(named: "IMG_0001.JPG")
        if let image = image {
            let renderimage = image.imageCroppingBezierPath(path: UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x:image.size.width/2,y:image.size.width/2 )  , radius: 200, startAngle: 0, endAngle:  (2 * CGFloat(M_PI) ), clockwise: true) )
                imageOutlet.image = renderimage
        }
    }
}


extension UIImage {
    func imageCroppingBezierPath(path:UIBezierPath) ->UIImage {

        let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height)

        //Defining a graphic context  to paint on
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, false, 0.0)
        //Get the current graphics context (if it exists)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        //save the current graphic context
        context?.saveGState()
        // clipping area
        path.addClip()
        self.draw(in: frame)

        //To extract an image from our canvas
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        //restore graphic context
        context?.restoreGState()
        //remove current context from stack
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image!
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
# import QuartzCore framework
imageView.layer.cornerRadius=imgvwUser.frame.size.width/2;
imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

The height and the width of the imageView must be same to get rounded corners.