# Custom UIButton iOS App

Tags: ios, uibutton

I'm developing an iOS app and i have to insert an UIButton.

I want to customize this button and i'd like to have a button like this:

[image]

My code is this, but i'm not able to make rounded corners:

```
_topImagesScrollViewButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
_topImagesScrollViewButton.frame = CGRectMake(screenWidth/2-25, topBarHeight+paddHeight, 37 , 37);
_topImagesScrollViewButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:red_middle green:green_middle blue:blue_middle alpha:alpha_middle];
[_topImagesScrollViewButton setTitle:@"Top" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_topImagesScrollViewButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:red_text green:green_text blue:blue_text alpha:alpha_text] forState:UIControlStateNormal];forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_topImagesScrollViewButton addTarget:self action:@selector(topImagesScrollVieButtonTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

How can i do?

Comment: The font type is not a problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to make UIView with rounded corners: [IOS: create a UIImage or UIImageView with rounded corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705879/ios-create-a-uiimage-or-uiimageview-with-rounded-corners)

And what about text color... everything seems to be ok. Maybe it doesn't work because you set title color twice for the same state. And the second from the bottom string of your code is excess.

Comment: I don't think that this oval shape can be achived with ``cornerRadius`` and ``clipsToBounds``.

Comment: Ok, for the text color you're right! i didn't see the error. I've updated the answer, it works good! thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I would use the above image to set the image of the button, instead of drawing the shape:

```
[_topImagesScrollViewButton setImage:@"yourimagename.png" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: It is not so easy, this button is in a scrollview and its width changes when the user scrolls. If I insert the image, it will be ruined

Comment: For the text color check that the RGB values are between 0.0 and 1.0. I don't really understand why do you need to draw the view by hand, but keep in mind that you'll probably get worst performance if you do that.

Comment: I've found this with a quick Google search. Drawing an ellipse using Quartz2D http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_4_iPhone_Graphics_Drawing_Tutorial_using_Quartz_2D#Drawing_an_Ellipse_or_Circle