# How to make UIImageView as a circle [iOS]

Tags: ios

I have an `UIImageView`. I want to make it as a circle type and 5 pixel red color border around it.

How it is possible? I share code and image also. Please anybody help me ?

[image]

My code is:

```
UIImageView *myImageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(130, 200, 60, 60)];
[myImageview setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
[self.view addSubview:myImageview];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [IOS: create a UIImage or UIImageView with rounded corners](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705879/ios-create-a-uiimage-or-uiimageview-with-rounded-corners)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply you can make it.

Just follow this code..

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

[myImageview.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor redColor] CGColor]]; // For border color
[myImageview.layer setBorderWidth:5.0]; // For Border width
[myImageview.layer setCornerRadius:45.0f]; // For Corner radious
[myImageview.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this on the UIImageView:

```
myImageview.layer.cornerRadius = myImageview.width / 2;
myImageview.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
myImageview.layer.borderWidth = 5.0f;
myImageview.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];

myImageview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
```

Comment: myImageview.bounds.size.width / 2 is correct way to call "width"

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have the [QuartzCore](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/QuartzCoreRefCollection/_index.html) framework in you project, then import `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` in the file where you create this image view.

```
UIImageView *myImageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(130, 200, 60, 60)];
[myImageview setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];

myImageview.clipsToBounds = YES:
myImageview.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
myImageview.layer.cornerRadius = myImageview.bounds.width / 2.0f;
myImageview.layer.borderWidth = 5.0;
myImageview.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor];


[self.view addSubview:myImageview];
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3 Solution:**

```
extension UIImageView{
    var circled : UIImageView{
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.width / 2;
        self.layer.borderWidth = 2
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        self.clipsToBounds = true
        return self
    }
}
```

usage:

```
imageView?.circled.image = UIImage()
```

Answer (score 0):

import `QuartzCore` framework
then in your .h file

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Then just do the following

```
UIImageView *myImageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(130, 200, 60, 60)];
[myImageview setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
myImageview.layer.cornerRadius = 30;
myImageview.layer.borderWidth = 5.0; // or whatever width you want to apply
myImageview.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
[self.view addSubview:myImageview];
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to add QuartzCore framework in your project, then`#import<QuartzCore/QuartzCore. h>` in the file where you're creating that image view.

```
UIImageView *myImageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(130, 200, 60, 60)];
[myImageview setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
myImageview.clipsToBounds = YES:
[self.view addSubview:myImageview];
[self updateImageViewLayer:myImageview.layer withBorderColor:[UIColor redColor] borderWidth:5.f cornerRadius:(myImageview.bounds.width/2.f)];

- (void)updateImageViewLayer:(CALayer*)layer withBorderColor:(UIColor *)color borderWidth:(CGFloat)width cornerRadius:(CGFloat)radius
{
    layer.borderWidth = width;
    layer.borderColor = color.CGColor;
    layer.cornerRadius = radius / 2.f;
    layer.masksToBounds = YES;
}
```

I make a function for reuse it for different `UIImageView` objects.

Answer (score 0):

When using autolayout, this could be useful:

```
class CircleImageView: UIImageView {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        cornerRadius = self.frame.width/2
    }
}
```